# Hive external table - Not giving correct count after replacing the underlying data file with a new file containing different number of records

Tags: hadoop, hive

It is noticed that `count(*)` does not give the updated count, after replacing the already existing data file, with a new file containing different number of records, in the HDFS location of the external table.

Is there a way to refresh this value? Or, will it get automatically refreshed after a configurable time duration?

Comment: Is the table partitioned?
And also check the location to which the table is pointing to, use the following command to check the same.
"show create table <table-name>"

Comment: @Nanda : No, it is not partitioned. But "select" gives the latest records. "show create table" gives correct location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hive maintains a cache of some table statistics including the number of rows. Try executing `ANALYZE TABLE tablename COMPUTE STATISTICS` to update these cached stats and run the query again. See [Statistics in Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) for details.

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. Previous observation: The first time I executed count( * ) the MR jobs ran, then I replaced the data-file. On subsequent occasions I ran count( * ) the MR jobs did not run and the count (the old value) was returned, probably from meta-store or cache. Current observation: Every time I execute count( * ) even after replacing the data-file, the MR jobs run and give correct result. I don't know why.

Comment: Perfect!! After a long-while I again ran over the same kind of problem.  
This is the sequence:  
1. There were records already in a hive external table.  
2. I deleted the data from its respective hdfs table.  
3. I ran the count(*) query.  
4. It showed the record-count that was available before I deleted the data files.  
5. Now I ran the command you suggested.  It gave the result as zero, the correct result. Thanks.

Comment: This is not working after deleting the underlaying files. Seems some bug